# Pycharm professional syntax highlighting for JS contained in a block inside a script tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates, pycharm

While writing JS for a Django application using the Django templating language, I am getting a weird formatting problem as below:
Defining a `domready` block in the `base.html` file:

```
<script>
    const csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        //DOM loaded
        {% block domready %}
        {% endblock %}
    })
</script>
```

Using the block in another template file `list.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block domready %}
    var page = 1;
    var emptyPage = false;
    var blockRequest = false;

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
    var margin = document.body.clientHeight - window.innerHeight - 200;
    if (window.pageYOffset > margin && !emptyPage && !blockRequest) {
    blockRequest = true;
    page += 1;
    fetch('?images_only=1&page=' + page).then(response => response.text()).then(html => {
    if (html === "") {
    emptyPage = true;
    } else {
    var imageList = document.getElementById('image-list');
    imageList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
    blockRequest = false;
    }
    })
    }
    });
    // start a synthetic scroll event on page load so that the next page loads in case the browser window is big enough
    const scrollEvent = new Event('scroll');
    window.dispatchEvent(scrollEvent);
{% endblock %}
```

Pycharm's formatting for JS code is not working in the `list.html` file. Is there any way to force Pycharm Professional to highlight the syntax and format the JS code in the `domready` block inside `list.html` file?

I was expecting that the indentation and syntax highlighting would work for the JS code inside the `domready` block but Pycharm Prof. is assuming this block to be a block of HTML code. Is there any way to force Pycharm to recognise this as JS code?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to solve this is:

- Highlight the code in question
- Right click and select 'Show Context Actions'
- In the menu that pops up - select 'Inject Language or Reference'
- In the next menu select 'Javascript'

Now it knows that code block should be formatted as javascript

Comment: After doing the right click and selecting "Show Context Actions", I am getting only the following 3 options:
1. Create new scratch file from selection
2. Wrap with 'trans' tag
3. Adjust code style settings

I tried doing this as well: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-language-injections.html

But this does not work as well.

Comment: instead of selecting the code and right click, try to put the cursor on a blank line then right click - context actions - language injection should be there

Comment: Tried that as well. Its simply not showing up if I keep my cursor on a blank line or on the first line of the JS code. It says "No context actions available at this location".

Comment: weird..this is what I just did trying to track down the problem, create a new html file, right click somewhere and confirm that the inject langage option pops up, I noticed that if my cursor is somewhere outside of the <html> tags it said 'no context options...' but if my cursor is for example between the <body> tags it did work - so it might have to do with where your cursor is

Comment: In my case, there are no HTML tags as the code is entirely JS. Hence, I am not seeing any option to inject the language of choice in Pycharm. But anyways, thanks for your help :)

Comment: ok i think your going to want to move your {% block %} tag, so that the <script> tag is in list.html or change your list.html file to be called list.js

Comment: Understood. Thanks. Will make some changes to the code.